# Replacing a hash with a variable when calling a function

Tags: function, perl, hash

What I want to do is replace the function call:

```
my_function({'param1' => 123, 'param2' => 456});
```

with:

```
my %tmp = {'param1' => 123, 'param2' => 456};
my_function(%tmp);
```

I get the run-time error message:

```
Can't use string ("HASH(0x16cffb0)") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

This does not do what you want:

```
my %tmp = {param1 => 123, param2 => 456};
```

You are trying to assign a hash reference to a hash. This raises warning:

```
Reference found where even-sized list expected at -e line 4.
```

Moral: always `use strict; use warnings;`, so such error is spotted quickly.

Your function appears to take a hash *reference* as argument. So either build a hash and pass it by reference:

```
my %tmp = (param1 => 123, param2 => 456);
my_function(\%tmp);
```

Or build a hash reference and pass it as-is:

```
my $tmp = {param1 => 123, param2 => 456};
my_function($tmp);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your function looks like it expects a **reference** to a hash (which is a scalar in Perl):

```
my $tmp = {'param1' => 123, 'param2' => 456};
my_function($tmp);
```

Curly braces (`{}`) are used to create a hash reference.

Refer to [perldoc perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> my %tmp = {'param1' => 123, 'param2' => 456};
> ```

A hash is initialised with a list. And lists are defined using round brackets:

```
my %tmp = ('param1' => 123, 'param2' => 456);
```

You can then take a reference to that hash and pass the reference to your subroutine:

```
my_function(\%tmp);
```

Alternatively, you can use the `{ ... }` to create an **anonymous** hash and get the reference to it immediately:

```
# Note that $tmp is a scalar as it contains
# a reference, not a hash.
my $tmp = {'param1' => 123, 'param2' => 456};
```

You can then pass that reference to your subroutine:

```
my_function($tmp);
```